# Model textBox field passing as null value to controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

Date TextBox Field passing as null value from View to Controller

Here is my Model class

```
public class VehcileMakeModel
    {
        //public VehicleModel VehicleModel { get; set; }
        //public List<VehicleMake> VehcileMakeList { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
        public DateTime? Year { get; set; } 

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
        [Display(Name = "Make")]
        public int SelectedMake { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MakesList { get; set; }
    }
```

Strongly Typed View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.VehcileMakeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateMakeModel";
}

<h2>CreateModel</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveModel", "iRateBook"))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Select Make")</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Model </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Model Year</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Year)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </td></tr>
</table>
}
```

When i click on Save button entered textbox values must pass to controller.

Controller Name

```
public ActionResult SaveModel(VehcileMakeModel VMM)
        {
            int ? makeid = VMM.SelectedMake;
            string strModel = VMM.Model.ToString();

            VehicleDataContext obj = new VehicleDataContext();
           // obj.VehicleModels.Add(VMM);

            obj.SaveChanges();


            return View("index");
        }
```

[image]

Why Yer field passing as Null value in Controller?

Comment: You may have entered invalid date in it.

Comment: I entered as 2017

Comment: You are correct Anupam Singh, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you specified Year property as DateTime? and not as int/string.
Default model binder expects dates to be sent in format defined by application culture. For example if you set in web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Model binder will expect MM/dd/yyyy date format (excluding time part.

Since you need only a year, I would simply change Year property to be integer

```
public int? Year { get; set; }
```

If you really need a DateTime? property on the model (which I doubt), you can create it it based on Year property:

```
public class VehcileMakeModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? Year { get; set; } 

    public DateTime? YearDt
    {
         return this.Year.HasValue ? new DateTime(this.Year.Value,1,1) : null;
    }
}
```